# How to avoid "Cannot proceed into method unless mocked type is injectable or dynamic"?

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking, jmockit

**In general**: Is it possible to call original implementation of method for objects I do not create myself? I mean, I am able to call `inv.proceed()` for instances I create in test code, but I do not know how to do it for instances created in code under test. The reason is, the only way I know of mocking instances out of my control is using `@Mocked` annotation but it makes `inv.proceed()` fail with `UnsupportedOperationException'.

**In detail**: I get this error with code like below:

```
new NonStrictExpectations() {
    @Mocked("process")
    MyClassUnderTest o;
    {
        o.process(any);
        result = new Delegate<MyClassUnderTest>() {
            public void process(Invocation inv, Object o) {
                inv.proceed(); //Fails on this line with UnsupportedOperationException
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The exception vanishes when I use dynamic partial mocking:

```
new NonStrictExpectations(o) {
    {
        o.process(any);
        result = new Delegate<MyClassUnderTest>() {
            public void process(Invocation inv, Object o) {
                inv.proceed();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I do not get it. Isn't it that @Mocked is "Injectable" ?